# Oracle spatial data

Tags: c#, oracle, spatial

I have an oracle database with which when I view in SQL Dev I get

```
FID,COORDINATE,SPACIALKEY
-------------------------------
13,(BLOB),1137686671492382720
```

When I access this using entity framework 6 the coordinate becomes a byte array containing around 800 items.

I know that this data is used to plot a polygon on a map but I have no idea on how to go about converting this into X,Y coordinates so that I can plot with leaflet.js

Comment: is the coordinate field a geometry data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer assuming the COORDINATE field is actually a GEOMETRY data type in Oracle, and can therefore store Point, lines, or Polygon features (so the concept of lat lon only really applies if you calculate a centroid).

In all the calls I make, I usually use this function to turn the geometry into its Well Known Text (WKT) representation.

```
SELECT SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(COORDINATE) AS WKT FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE . . .;
```

Most front end vis technologies handle WKT.

If for some reason you only want lat longs, you can use the methods on the geometry themselves to get that on a centroid like this

```
select 
SDO_GEOM.sdo_centroid(a.COORDINATE, m.diminfo).sdo_point.x as X,
SDO_GEOM.sdo_centroid(a.COORDINATE, m.diminfo).sdo_point.y as Y
from yourTable a ,  user_sdo_geom_metadata m
 WHERE m.table_name = 'yourTable' AND m.column_name = 'COORDINATE'
```

which returns x = lon, y=lat, but be aware that if you have complex geometries, the centroid can be very misleading, depending on what your doing.

HTH

G$

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you can handle geom object in EF. Just create and aditional column `geom_txt` on your model.

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET geom_txt = COORDINATE.Get_WKT();
```

You get a [WKT](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_Known_Text) and leaflet can handle very easy, something like this:

```
LINESTRING (30 10, 10 30, 40 40)
POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot edit the database... any other ideas?

Comment: Not sure, check if this post help. https://mapoholic.wordpress.com/2015/12/01/display-oracle-spatial-data-on-a-leaflet-map/

Comment: Yeah read that already - requires adding functions into database I believe

Comment: Yes, I just see it.  That is what I tought, you need create the function on db. If you cant edit that db, will need create another db where you can have access so can move the geom and then create the geojson. https://mapoholic.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/sdo2geojson.png